# Publish my API to my website and use it my build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, repository

So ive followed https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_building_java_libraries.html and created the base of a library. I've added a little method in it to add two numbers as a test. I was wondering how would I go about publishing this to my website https://jonahm.dev and then using it in my build.gradle in another project like `implementation dev.jonahm:test:1.0`

Comment: You need to host a _repository_, with either something like Nexus or [at Central](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/).

Comment: so I can't use my own website?

Comment: You need to learn a bit more about the technical workings of the Web. You can use your own _server_, but for dependencies you need to publish in the _Maven repository layout_. This can be done by creating the necessary metadata files and uploading them all to a directory on your Web site, but this is a lot of trouble unless you're just doing it once to learn.

Comment: okay thanks! ill look into https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/